# Simulation works with n= 100 but not n = 300

Tags: r, simulation

Is there a reason this would work for one sample size but not when increased? Been working on it for a while and n=100 runs fine. It is a simulation that generates data for X1, X2, and error, and then uses those values to compute the Y value.

```
###Change to sample size n2=300
n1<-100
n2<- 300
n3 <- 1000 
ITER <- 500

#set beta coefficients
B0 <- 1
B1 <- 1
B2 <- 1
B3_1 <-1
B3_2 <- 2
B3_3 <- 5
#set gamma values
c1 <-.1
c2 <- .25
c3 <- .75
sim10 <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = ITER, ncol = 4)

colnames(sim10) <- c("Y", "X1", "X2", "E")

# simulate X1s,
for (i in 1:ITER){
sim10[,2] <-runif(n2, -3, 3)
}

# simulate X2s
for(i in 1:ITER){
sim10[,3] <-  (c1*sim10[,2])+ rnorm(n2,0,1)
}

# simulate error
for(i in 1:ITER){
sim10[,4] <- dnorm(300, 0,1)  
}

# y's
for(i in 1:ITER)
sim10[,1] <- B0+ B1*sim10[,2] + B2*sim10[,3] + B3_1*(sim10[,3]^2) + 
sim10[,4]
```

Comment: What error do you get when you increase n? Or if there is no error how is the output different than you expect?

Comment: Uncommented n2, I had been troubleshooting it and forgot. The error is number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Since you have `ITER=500` the dimensions of `sim10` do not match either 100 or 300. However since 100 divides 500, the code throws no error when n=100 because it repeats the 100 values 5 times. 300 does not divide 500 so the code throws an error. I think the simulation is not doing what you think it's doing even when n=100.

Comment: `ITER` must be multiple of `n2`. You try to fill out columns of a matrix with `ITER` number of rows by formulas dependent on `n2` `rnorm` generated values, which is impossible unless `ITER` is multiple of `n2`.

Comment: The task is to simulate 500 iterations of 3 sample sizes (100, 300, 1000) and vary 3 values of c as well as 3 values of B3. Do you have any suggestions as to how to restructure the code?